# Graphql subscription not getting client-side variables

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I am trying to subscribe to a graphql-yoga subscription using apollo-client useSubscription hook

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSubscription,gql} from '@apollo/client';

const SUB_NEW_MSG = gql`
    subscription SUB_NEW_MSG($chatRoom:ID!)
    {
        newMessage(chatRoom:$chatRoom)
    }`;


function NewMsg(){

    const { loading,error,data } = useSubscription(SUB_NEW_MSG,{
        variables:{
            chatRoom: "608851227be4796a8463607a",
        },
    });
    
    if(loading) return <p>loading...</p>;
    if(error) return <p>{error}</p>;
    
    console.log(data);
    return <h4>New Message:{data.newMessage}</h4>;
}
```

[Network Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flkSZ.png)

But gives an error-
**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Variable "$chatRoom" of required type "ID!" was not provided.). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

The schema at the backend is

```
type Subscription{
    newMessage(chatRoom: ID!): String!
}
```

resolver is

```
const { pubsub } = require("../helper");
const { withFilter } = require("graphql-yoga");

module.exports = {
    Subscription: {
        newMessage: {
            subscribe: withFilter(
                () => pubsub.asyncIterator("newMessage"),
                (payload, variables) => {
                    console.log(payload.query, variables, "HALO");
                    return payload.chatRoom === variables.chatRoom;
                }
            ),
        },
    },
};
```

**But when I pass the query like below,with no variables to useSubscription hook.Then it works**

```
const SUB_NEW_MSG = gql`
    subscription SUB_NEW_MSG
    {
        newMessage(chatRoom:"608851227be4796a8463607a")
    }`;
```

What should I do?Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this, and test it.

```
const SUB_NEW_MSG = gql`
  subscription SUB_NEW_MSG($chatRoom: String!) {
    newMessage(chatRoom: $chatRoom)
  }
`;
```